# rails s -b $IP -p $PORT, meaning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9

I'm new to coding and using cloud 9. I know I need to use the command "rails s -b $IP -p $PORT" to run my rails server in Cloud 9. I was hoping someone could take the time to break this command down into its basic parts and explain what exactly this command means and why it works? I have yet to find anything to explain step by step what this command is doing and I would love to know.

Answer (score 3):

- `s` is the shorthand for `server`, which means that you want Rails to start the web server.
- `-b $IP` **binds** the IP the server is binded to. By default it will be binded to localhost, so it would only be accessible from the same machine the server is running in. By binding it to a particular IP you can let the server listen at a different network interface, maybe one attached to the public Internet.
- `-p $PORT` sets the **port** the server will run at. By default it is 3000, but you can change that using this parameter. Note that setting it to a port lower than 1024 will most likely require permissions.

`$IP` and `$PORT` are the environment variables set by Cloud 9 to let the server know which IP and which port is it actually supposed to run in.